# How to Configure Notification for New Admin User Created

Tags: magento-1.9, adminnotification, magento-1.9.3.10

With the recent release of Magento 1.9.3.10 in September 2018, there is a new option to send an email notification when a new admin account is created. I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

I have found where I can enable or disable this functionality at `Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > New Admin User Create Notification`

After enabling the option, I cleared cache and then created a new admin user. We have multiple admins created, but none of them received any notifications.

1. How does Magento determine the email address it uses to send this new
   notification?
2. I couldn't find anywhere that I could configure this, did I miss
   something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The `New Admin User Created` notification isn't sent to any of the current admins, it's sent to the email address that is configured for the `General Contact` in *Configuration > General > Store Email Addresses*.

Answer (score 0):

The issue still exist in Magento 2.4.2-p2

Here `vendor/magento/module-user/Model/Notificator.php:139`
it returns NULL from `$this->deployConfig->get('user_admin_email')`

Tested on freshly installed version.

Comment: That is not the same issue.